# Node.js rest api validate incoming json from url

Tags: node.js, mongoose, jsonschema

I have a simple rest api that excepts json in a url through a get request.

I have a mongoose schema and I would like to validate that the incoming json is in the correct format.

Can I do this with Mongoose alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create a document from the parsed JSON using the model and [`validate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-validate).

```
// assuming you haven't parsed the JSON yet
var doc = MyModel(JSON.parse(json_from_url));
doc.validate(function(err) {...});
```

Note: most mongoose queries will validate a document before saving it to the database.

Comment: Thanks for replying, so if my schema is { test: String } and the json_from_url is { something: 123 } how does this validate, or if there are partial fields. Can I define the schema to have required or null values?

Comment: yes? the schema can define a field as required or defaulted to a value. **read the docs.**

Comment: @CharlesBryant, yes there are some built in [validators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) and you can also specify your own. I figured you had this covered given you said you already have a schema.